# Windows Phone How populate ListPicker from text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, listpicker

I'm developing a windows phone app, and i need populate my ListPicker (ToolKit) from text file stored in isolatedStorage (teste.txt).
How better way to do it?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ProdutoLpk" Width="305" FullModeHeader="SELECT" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed"/>
```

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in a couple of fairly small steps:

1. First, you need to load the items from your text file - personally, I'd have a view-model that represents each item, but you could create a `List<string>` if you prefer
2. Then, you need to bind that collection of items to the ListPicker's `ItemsSource` property

There's quite a good [example on the GeekChamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth) website, but to go the step further, and assuming you've done the work to put your collection of selectable objects on your view-model (DataConteext), you could have something like this in your XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ProdutoLpk" Width="305" FullModeHeader="SELECT"
    ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12 0 0 0"/>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
<!-- where your view-model has a "Products" property with the selectable
     products, with each item having a "Name" property -->
```